# Cron job to start on a dynamic time using MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, cron

Imagine I'm performing several overnight jobs across different databases and I want to predefine different starting times per DB stored in a control table in MySQL.

Is there a way to start a cron job based on the returned value of a MySQL query?

To make myself clear, imagine a table with

Client_name   |   Batch_start_time
"Client A"    |   0:30
"Client B"    |   3:30
"Client C"    |   5:00

I want to be able to tune up the batch times without editing crontab

Thanks

Comment: What MySQL version do you have? Could MySQL's own [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html) be a possible alternative to cron for you? I've not yet done much with these events myself, but I've been looking into a potential future use. Here's one [small example](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/) at sitepoint.